# How to resolve loader in webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Using `webpack` version `4.6.0`

I need to resolve the path of a loader using webpack.

The loader is used like this in a `node_modules` dependency:

```
const loadedIndex = require('!!../loaders/A-loader!./index.js');
```

I want to override this loader `A-loader` with another `B-loader`.

Here is how my project is structured:

```
_ directory
  |_ node_modules
     |_ lib
        |_ loaders/A-loader.js
        |_ index.js
  |_ loaders/B-loader.js
```

I want to use webpack [`resolveLoader`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader) in order to replace the current `A-loader` into `B-loader`.

I'm not sure how to use it, I try but this doesn't work:

```
{
    resolveLoader {
          alias: { 
               'A-loader': 'path/to/my/directory/loaders/B-loaders.js'
          } 
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Comment: Try looking here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ this is the updated api, documentations is under update, so do not rely too much on that. Try looking at the alias under resolve.

Comment: Keep your `resolveLoader` solution, but do `require('!!A-loader!./index.js');` instead. I'm not sure what you have already tried when you say "but this doesn't work", so I can't give this as an answer. If it solves the problem tell me so that I can add it as an answer